# Graphic for retina display not working for IPAD

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

I am going to update my app for retina display.For this purpose I have set image name with @2x  suffix.But iPad 3 not load hd graphic. I also try with suffix @2x~ipad but no any luck.
How can I set retina graphic for IPad3?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@2x~ipad postfix should do the trick, there might be something else wrong.

Comment: @Jake Thanks for replay. Is we need to enable any setting for retina display

Answer (score 0):

When you load the image, leave off the suffix.  For example, do

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
```

and not

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, I use myImage.png (your second method), and it works fine even with retina images.

Comment: I wonder if that's something that was ever true then.  I couldn't get the OS to recognize any of my @2x images and -landscape, etc. modifiers until I removed the suffix from the name.  That was under iOS 4 and either it was something else I did at the same time which fixed things or Apple fixed it for iOS 5.